# Symfony Doctrine generate tables in DB

Tags: symfony, doctrine

i'm using symphony with doctrine , i generated an entity and I'm trying to generate tables in data base with the console with the command

php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql

i receive this error :

[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
  [Semantical Error] The annotation "@ORM\Table" in class bouda\platformBundle\Entity\Advert was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

i tried to add  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM; in the Entity file but when i save the file le line is deleted automatically .

By the way i'm using sublime text and MAMP in os x

Comment: Do you have any thing running in Sublime that modifies files on save?

Comment: This is the first time that sublime modifies my file on save , to answer your question no i don't think so. like said in my response it worked for me , and after seeing your response i tried to add another **use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;** and save the file and both of the statements was deleted on the save and the same problem happened again , really don't understand the phenomena

Comment: This was done by sublime , i tried to open the file with another editor and it worked t

Answer (score 0):

Soved , don't know why couldn't modify the entity file with adding **use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;** statement so i just generated another instance of the entity and this time the **use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;** statement was included in the file and the tables was generated with no problem

The pluggin in Sublime that was deleting the statement is **phpTools**

Comment: I think doctrine does not recongnize usage classes in php annotation and just optimize it out.